# Использование Resources C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, resources, listbox

На форме есть comboBox1 или listBox1.
В папке Resources есть file.txt, с содержанием:

```
текст_1
текст_2
текст_3
и т.д.
```

Как заполнить comboBox1 или listBox1 данными из file.txt, так чтобы каждая строка была отдельным item-ом.

```
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"Resources\file.txt");
            String line = sr.ReadLine();

            while (line != null)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            sr.Close();
```

Пишет, что не существует пути. Возможно проблема в том что при компиляции, не создаётся папка с Resources. Хотя файл добавлен через ресурсы, действие при сборке - Resource, Копировать в выходной каталог - Всегда копировать

Comment: А зачам вы файл добавляете в ресурсы? Почему не просто на диске? В чем цель? Какой Build Target стоит у файла? Resource или Embedded Resource? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3314213/12888024

Comment: Resource. В данном файле будут храниться параметры для выбора. А .txt файл, чтобы можно было редактировать их любому человеку. Добавляю в ресурсы, чтобы при установке на любой компьютер, не пришлось, каждый раз искать данный файл и добавлять

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: Ресурсы невозможно редактировать. Если хотите чтобы у вас был редактируемый файл, то вам нужен не ресурс, а просто файл, который будет копироваться в директирию сборки. Поставьте корректный Build Action, подходящий под вашу задачу. Параметре Copy to output folder выставить тоже надо в например Copy if newer